# C + + calls shell commands containing sudo, resulting in deadlock

Tags: c++, shell

When I call `sudo sleep 1000`, a while loop outside me gets stuck. How can I solve it?
The calling method is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <thread>

class popen2 {
public:
    FILE *in{nullptr};
    FILE *out{nullptr};
    pid_t pid{0};
    int rcode{-1};

    popen2() {
        string cmd;
        int pfd[2]{0};

     if (pfd[0] != STDIN_FILENO) {
        dup2(pfd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(pfd[0]);
     }
        if (pfd[1] != STDOUT_FILENO) {
            dup2(pfd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(pfd[1]);
         }

       execl("/bin/bash", "sh", "-c", "sudo sleep 1000", (char *) 0);

       _exit(127);
        }
        /* parent */
        this->in = fdopen(pfd[1], "w");
        this->out = fdopen(pfd[0], "r");
    }

    ~popen2() {
        if (pid == 0)
            return; /* wasn't opened */
        if (fclose(in) == EOF)
            return;
        if (fclose(out) == EOF)
            return;
        while (waitpid(pid, &rcode, 0) < 0)
            if (errno != EINTR)
                return; /* error other than EINTR from waitpid() */
    }

    int poll() {
        return waitpid(pid, &rcode, WNOHANG);
    }

    int kill(int sig = SIGKILL) {
        return ::kill(this->pid, sig);
    }
};
```

use:

```
    popen2 p();
    fcntl(fileno(p.out), F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    auto tmStart = sh::utils::NowTime();
    while (true) {
        while (fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), p.out) != NULL)
            out.append(tmp);
        if (p.poll() > 0)
            break;
        if (sh::utils::NowTime() - tmStart > timeout) {
            p.kill();
            std::cout << "cmd timeout.\n";
        }
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
```

Comment: _" a while loop outside me gets stuck"_ - what does that mean? Where's the `while` loop? Unrelated: Don't do `(char *) 0`. Use `nullptr` instead.

Comment: Hi. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and most importantly, how to make a [mre]!

Comment: @TedLyngmo The cast to `char*` is required here. The function is a variadic function and expects a `char*` null pointer value.

Comment: I'd guess `sudo` is attempting to prompt for the password and not getting any response. Why are you sleeping with sudo? Why are you even using `exec` to sleep rather than using `std::this_thread::sleep`?

Comment: @user17732522 Wouldn't `nullptr` be fine as a `char*`? No cast needed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `std::nullptr_t` is cast to `void*` in default argument promotion (which I didn't realize before). I suppose that is technically the wrong type.

Comment: `nullptr` can be used everywhere where a pointer is required and is usually preferred over `NULL` or `(char*)0` etc. _"may be implicitly converted to any pointer and pointer to member type."_

Comment: @TedLyngmo just oddiness of C function. Presumably on most platforms with POSIX   API you'd be right, but formally from C point of view that's wrong. OP have to consider that they use  documentation for C API in C++ program.

Comment: @TedLyngmo There are no implicit conversions done, because there is no target type. Only default argument promotions are done. This gives an argument `nullptr` the type `void*`, not `char*` as the function expects. The two types are not compatible, so technically UB. It is a C-style variadic function, like `printf`. As mentioned above it will most likely work in practice though, assuming that `void*` and `char*` have same representations.

Comment: @user17732522 and it might be promoted to wrong size of argument on some platforms, that's it.

Comment: Add overall call code

Comment: I get your points. I missed the fact that it's variadic and not a `char*` argument. I don't think Posix has anything to do with it though. I wouid be wrong even if it was a pure C++ variadic function . :-)

Comment: The shown code has mismatched braces and won't compile.

Comment: Note that `execl` just like any function of `spawn` family  *replaces* current process by executed one. Unless you had used `fork()`, your process no longer exists, and loop in the calling branch of `fork()` wouldn't work anyway as loop in the main branch  requires special work to additional with called process. You have to show minimal code which surrounds this call

Comment: add some include

Answer (score 1):

```
execl("/bin/bash", "sh", "-c", "sudo sleep 1000", (char *) 0);
```

At this point your process no longer exists.

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with
> a new process image. The functions described in this manual page are
> front-ends for execve(2). (See the manual page for execve(2) for
> further details about the replacement of the current process image.)

Usually those are used with `fork()` but I'm not sure why you even trying to call an externall process at this point, just for `sleep` (which exists as a function)